# Highcharts 3D pie with custom colors

Tags: highcharts

I have modified the standard 3d pie jsfiddle (see link). I would like to use custom colors in my 3d pie chart but when I do, it loses the shading on the 3d effect. Any ideas how to fix this?

```
colors: ['green', 'orange', 'red', 'pink', 'lime' ],
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kmjones77/fyzL90sb/

Thanks,

Ken

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the color names with their hex value equivalent ([found here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_colornames.asp)):

```
colors: ['#008000', '#FFA500', '#FF0000', '#FFC0CB', '#00FF00']
```

See [JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/fyzL90sb/1/).

I think the cause might be the `Highcharts.Color` object type having trouble using it's `brighten` functionality when the color is set using a color name instead of some other value type.

Comment: That's true - Highcharts library doesn't translate color-names into some usable format.